# What happens to duplicate question when original question got deleted?

Tags: support

Lets assume that there are two Questions on DA say **POST-A** and **POST-B** posted by different users.

**POST-A** is marked as duplicate of **POST-B**.

I would like to know what happens to **POST-A** if post-B got deleted by it's owner? Will **POST-A** be automatically reopened?

I don't know whether DA has this feature or not, I didn't find a way to test this.

Comment: Has this actually happened anywhere?

Comment: @MPD No, I didn't find this case in DA, but I'm just eager to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my observations, there is no automatic reopening.

However, I've only seen this happen when one person keeps asking the same question over and over (usually in frustration over not getting any answers to the first version).  In that case, the later versions are sometimes closed as duplicates.  They are not automatically reopened when the first is self-deleted (nor should they, as this type of behaviour should not be encouraged).

I should add that in the case of similar questions asked by two *different* persons, this is very unlikely to happen.

The rules for self-deletion are:

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

And unless *POST-B* has *at least one upvoted answer*, it is very unlikely that *POST A* will be marked as a duplicate of it (posts are not marked as a duplicate *unless* the superior question pointed to has a usable answer).

If *POST-B* has at least one upvoted answer, it can't be self-deleted, so the situation will not occur.

Comment: *posts are not marked as a duplicate unless the superior question pointed to has a usable answer* **or** both are posted by the same user **or** diamond moderator closes them as dupes (happens if members of the same team post duplicates, as far as I have seen). And in the case of the same team, it is just as likely to happen as it is in case of one user.

Comment: Thanks Free Radical, and @Mołot. I got it. but still some confusion let me try to explain.
Let's assume that POST B has only one answer with 2 up-votes. So user (who posted the answer for POST B) can delete their post anytime. If so, POST A shouldn't be considered as duplicate of POST B.? In this scenario what happens? Sorry If I'm wrong

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Never seen it happening. People usually delete answers that are 1) bad or 2) good, but worse than other of the answers. In such situations it changes nothing. Never seen anyone to delete answer that's actually good, and only one. If I'll see, I will probably flag for moderator's attention asking to undelete (or disassociate from user who deleted, mark as community wiki, and then undelete).

Comment: @Mołot yes I agree, but this can happen, when user delete their answer because it is wrong, was written because misunderstanding of the question, or it is not an appropriate answer, and they notice that; even answer score is 3 (From my post http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/why-disciplined-badge)

Comment: @KrishnaMohan as far as I know there is no automatic reopening for such cases. And, as far as I observed, it is a good tradition on Metas to ignore problems that simply are not happening until they starts to happen often enough to overwork diamond moderators.

Comment: @Mołot Ok, thanks Molot, I didn't mean to prolong this question. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: @FreeRadical Thanks for you time and I got it now. :)